# iPhone SDK - How to take a picture with custom camera view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, camera, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

I want to release the shutter as soon as the user tabs on the screen. I have working code for displaying the camera in fullscreen mode. How can I trigger the shutter by a touch?

```
- (IBAction) takePicture
{
    if (!self.imgPicker) {
        self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    }

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.imgPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        self.imgPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

        CGAffineTransform cameraTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.132, 1.132);
        self.imgPicker.cameraViewTransform = cameraTransform;

        UIView *headsUpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

        [self.imgPicker setCameraOverlayView:headsUpView];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Camera not available.");
        self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;  
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the takePicutre method and then detect any touches on the screen.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture

Something like this

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    self.imgPicker.takePicture;
}
```